# The .net NameSpace Questions

Tags: c#, .net

I am very sorry that I do not say the problem very clearly. I provided some of the code for easier to understanding.

The project.aspx that I would like to call the function `getConnectionString()`:

`_conn = new OdbcConnection(FirstFunction.getConnectionString());`

The coding of the FirstFunction.class I created myself:

```
namespace myownfunction
{
     public string getConnectionString(){

     return "Database1";}
}
```

But the project.aspx cannot resolve the `getConnectionString()` using the namespace I created in the FirstFunction.class. It just know how to resolve using the namespace in the dll.

Comment: This question is hard to understand... please provide some code or protocode at least.

Comment: Consider using a decompiler. You may be able to look inside the DLL to see the underlying code. Here's a [**link**](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to a free decompiler.

Comment: Check your code, as it stand as the moment of typing this, you are placing getConnectionString directly on the namespace. Also you should check if there are not syntax errors in your code and adding your namespace with using.

Comment: Thank you for checking and make my code easily to read. My syntax should be alright. I just do not type some of the details of the coding for more easy to read. I call this function in other project. It works perfectly. The most weird things is I cannot use any function I created in the class only in this project.

Answer (score 3):

You can't place functions directly inside a namespace.  They have to be inside a class:

```
namespace myownfunction
{
   public class MyUtilities
   {
     public static string getConnectionString()
     {
         return "Database1";
     }
   }
}
```

Then you should be able to access this method with `myownfunction.MyUtilities.getConnectionString()`

Comment: Thank you for checking my code. I have tried your method but still not work.

Comment: It was missing a closing brace.  Please try again now.

Comment: No. I have confidence that the syntax for the class I created is perfectly correct. Because when I add the class in other project. I could call with no error. But just cannot use in this project.

Comment: You didn't create a class at all. It's just a function inside a namespace, which is not valid in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a reference to the assembly you created to your project ? Without that the resolve function won't be able to find your implementation.

I do have a question - in your example you are using 'Hello" you will only be able to see method thats are part of that class.

You can use extension methods to add new methods to a class you don't have source code access to. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: For the function I would like to call. I do not make it to a dll. I just write the function in the normal class. So I should not need to add a reference to the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) to learn about namespaces. There are a lot of examples that can make you their use clearer.

Comment: Reason for this downvote? He question was also incomplete at the moment of my answer.